# How to show a text from JTextField in other class?

Tags: java

I want to move the text entered into JTextField to another class in which this text will be displayed. Code of second class where the text is entered below:

```
public class Konto extends JFrame{

String newUser;

Konto(String newUser){
    this.newUser = newUser;
}
public void setUser(String text){
    this.newUser = text;
}

public String getTextField(){
    return this.text.getText();
}

public String getUser(){
    return this.newUser;
}

protected void back(ActionEvent e){

    //System.out.println(getTextField());
    this.setVisible(false);
    new Main().setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Code of first class where text is showed:

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
Konto k = new Konto();

public Main() {


    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
    this.setBounds(300, 200, 1000, 600);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

    initComponents();
}
public void initComponents(){
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.add(go);
    panel.add(show);

    go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            goAction(e);
        }
    });

    show.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            showS(e);
        }
    }); 
}
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton go = new JButton("new user");
JButton show = new JButton("show");

public void showS(ActionEvent e){
    k.setUser(k.getTextField());
    System.out.println(k.getUser());
}

private void goAction(ActionEvent e){
    this.setVisible(false);
    new Konto().setVisible(true);
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().setVisible(true);
}
```

}

So, when I change in ***void showS(ActionEvent e)*** a '*k.getTextField*' in k.setUser on e.g. **"Test123"**, in console will be showed **test123**, but if I leave it unchanged, in console won't be no one word.

```
k.setUser(k.getTextField()); -----> k.setUser("Test123");
```

I will be glad if you could solve my trouble :)

Comment: Where are you even calling your `showS()` method? This isn't all your code is it? I have to say, based on this question and the question you asked yesterday, you are in *way* over your head. You should dial back your expectations and take the time to properly study Java and Swing before resuming your project. You cannot expect people to provide this fundamental of education when you should be reading a book instead.

Comment: @Kris You are using two classes one for data entry and second display data, I'm right?

Comment: @MarsAtomic my method `showS()` is called when I press a button (by ActionListener). I just want know how to do it, when it's strange occurrence. I know when I want  override a String like this and show it in console: `String name1 = "Tom"; String name2 = name1; name2="Jerry"; sout(name2)` the console will showed **Tom**, because `name2 = new String(name1);` so what I do wrong?

Comment: @Coder1 that's right

Comment: You can use Oop here

Comment: I understand what the problem is, but if you don't show the code that actually uses showS(), how do you expect anyone to know what's happening? You may describe what you think is happening, but that's not the same as what's actually happening, now is it? You're correct in thinking that setUser should take any string arg, but that's not what's happening, so obviously something else is going on, but without code no one can prove a thing.

Comment: @Coder1 what's Oop ?

Comment: Like create  variables in class where textFields are present, fetch data from these fields and store in these variables. Call these variables from any class to set data

Comment: Oop stands for Object Oriented programming

Comment: @Coder1 ok, I'll try :)

Comment: Do not post code in the comments. Click the edit button and edit the text of your question.

Comment: Like create  variables in class where textFields are present, fetch data from these fields and store in these variables. Call these variables from any class to set data. For this you have to study Oop

Comment: @MarsAtomic edited

Comment: @Coder1 just don't know what does mean Oop. I've already studied it :)

Comment: Good! now it is time to practice some OOP

Comment: @Coder1 we learn all our lives but some things are difficult to understand, so I've asked a question what I wrong do :D

Comment: I can add information - when I invoke a `System.out.println(getTextField());` _(in protected void back(ActionEvent e), class Konto)_ and I press a button 'back' the text that I entered to JTextField is showed. So why the method `getTextField` doesn't work in class Main ?

Comment: @MarsAtomic could you tell me sth?